# Converting conditional constraints to linear constraints in Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming

I have two variables: x>= 0 and y binary (either 0 or 1), and I have a constant z >= 0. How can I use linear constraints to describe the following condition:

```
If x = z then y = 1 else y = 0.
```

I tried to solve this problem by defining another binary variable i and a large-enough positive constant U and adding constraints

```
y - U * i = 0;
x - U * (1 - i) = z;
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really there are two classes of constraints that you are asking about:

1. If `y=1`, then `x=z`. For some large constant `M`, you could add the following two constraints to achieve this:

```
x-z <= M*(1-y)
z-x <= M*(1-y)
```

If `y=1` then these constraints are equivalent to `x-z <= 0` and `z-x <= 0`, meaning `x=z`, and if `y=0`, then these constraints are `x-z <= M` and `z-x <= M`, which should not be binding if we selected a sufficiently large `M` value.

2. If `y=0` then `x != z`. Technically you could enforce this constraint by adding another binary variable `q` that controls whether `x > z` (`q=1`) or `x < z` (`q=0`). Then you could add the following constraints, where `m` is some small positive value and `M` is some large positive value:

```
x-z >= mq - M(1-q)
x-z <= Mq - m(1-q)
```

If `q=1` then these constraints bound `x-z` to the range `[m, M]`, and if `q=0` then these constraints bound `x-z` to the range `[-M, -m]`.

In practice when using a solver this usually will not actually ensure `x != z`, because small bounds violations are typically allowed. Therefore, instead of using these constraints I would suggest not adding any constraints to your model to enforce this rule. Then, if you get a final solution with `y=0` and `x=z`, you could adjust `x` to take value `x+epsilon` or `x-epsilon` for some infinitesimally small value of `epsilon`.

Comment: @Bosco sorry, I don't understand. `x=z` is easy to model (we did it in part 1). `x != z` is hard to model (as I describe in part 2).

Comment: Hi @josilber, so the condition is                                                                     x= z, result is y =1, or x != z, result is y =0; By your constraints, when x = z, 0 <= M*(1 - y), then y can be 1 or 0, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bosco basically I have enforced the logic "If `y=1` then `x=z`". I haven't added any logic for the case when `y=0`, so you could either have `x=z` or `x != z` in that case.

Comment: Hi @josilber, so I think I have to change the problem to if y= 0 then x = z, if y = 1, then x != z, then I get the answer :)

Comment: @Bosco As I state in my answer, I don't think you can easily model the `x != z` part using linear programming (please see my comment on your answer for why the approach you describe is more restrictive than `x != z`).

Comment: @Bosco I've updated my answer to show how to fully model `x != z` by adding another binary variable (which controls for whether `x > z` or `x < z`), and I've kept in the discussion of why I don't think in general that this will work very well.

Answer (score 0):

So I change the conditional constraints to

```
if x = z then y = 0 else y = 1
```

Then the answer will be

```
x - z <= M * y;
x - z >= m * y;
```

where M is a large enough positive number, m is a small enough positive number.

Comment: If `y=0` then these constraints state that `x=z` (just as my answer does). However if `y=1` then you are forcing `x-z` to take a value between `m` and `M`, meaning you have disallowed the case where `x != z` and `x < z`.

Comment: Hi @josilber, so what I can only do is to compare the range of x and z, my answer above is the case that x will never be smaller than z.