# Combinatorics: Efficiently Solving with Pulp - Large Dataset Issues

Tags: python, linear-programming, combinatorics, pulp

I have the below pulp implementation that assigns the best product (a or b) to each factory in `data` (1,2,3,4 or 5) with no issue, however after around 50 factories pulp seems unable to complete the solve (see `data2` which has 205 factories' data). Ideally I'd like to be able to solve this problem for ~1million factories (industrial units).

As an explanatory note, I am trying to minimise overall cost. There is a product cost, and an emissions inclusion / limit for each product. However, emissions are calculated in aggregate not at a factory level, thus, for the toy model using `data` if 2 factories are assigned to product "a" then the there is 2x60 (the `limit`) for those factories to emit before the excess charging would be applied `echarge_a`, and correspondingly there would be 3x100 for the remaining 3 factories to emit before excess charging would be applied: `echarge_b`.

```
# factory picker

import pulp

data = {
    'f1': (1.2,),
    'f2': (1.0,),
    'f3': (1.7,),
    'f4': (1.8,),
    'f5': (1.6,)
}

# unit_cost_b = 8
# limit_b = 100
# echarge_b = 0.004

# unit_cost_a = 5
# limit_a = 60
# echarge_a = 0.007

unit_cost = {'a': 5, 'b': 8}
limit = {'a': 60, 'b': 100}
echarge = {'a': 0.007, 'b': 0.004}

# conveniences....
factories = list(data.keys())
products = ['a', 'b']
fp = [(f, p) for f in factories for p in products]

### PROB SETUP
prob = pulp.LpProblem('factory_assignments', pulp.LpMinimize)

### VARS

# make[factory, product] == 1 if making that product, else 0...
make = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('make', fp, cat=pulp.LpBinary)

emission = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('emission', products, lowBound=0)

### OBJECTIVE

# a convenience expression...
tot_unit_cost = sum(unit_cost[p] * make[f, p] for f, p in fp)

prob += tot_unit_cost + sum(emission[p] for p in products)


### CONSTRAINTS

# constrain the emission to GTE the expression.  It already has a lowBound=0, so that
# handles the max() expression in a linear expression
for p in products:
    prob += emission[p] >= sum(make[f, p] * (data[f][0] - limit[p]) for f in factories) * echarge[p] * 31

# each factory must produce *something*  (and only 1 thing)  (this is implied in the orig problem)
for f in factories:
    prob += sum(make[f, p] for p in products) == 1

### QA it...
print(prob)

### SOLVE
soln = prob.solve()

for f, p in fp:
    if make[f, p].varValue:   # True if the variable is 1
        print(f'make {p} in factory {f}')

print(f'tot unit cost: {pulp.value(tot_unit_cost)}')

for p in products:
    print(f'emission cost for {p} is: {emission[p].varValue}')
```

--

```
data2=[0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
       2.9000000e-03, 4.1000000e-02, 5.0000000e-02, 5.0000000e-02,
       5.0000000e-02, 5.0000000e-02, 9.9600000e-02, 1.0000000e-01,
       1.0000000e-01, 1.0000000e-01, 1.0000000e-01, 1.0000000e-01,
       1.0000000e-01, 1.0000000e-01, 1.0000000e-01, 1.0000000e-01,
       1.3080000e-01, 1.5000000e-01, 1.9530000e-01, 2.0410000e-01,
       2.6460000e-01, 3.3200000e-01, 4.0000000e-01, 4.8920000e-01,
       5.9270000e-01, 7.4900000e-01, 1.0000000e+00, 1.2304000e+00,
       1.6982000e+00, 2.0000000e+00, 2.0000000e+00, 2.0000000e+00,
       2.0000000e+00, 2.0000000e+00, 2.0000000e+00, 2.0000000e+00,
       2.0500000e+00, 2.0500000e+00, 2.0500000e+00, 2.0500000e+00,
       2.1000000e+00, 2.1308000e+00, 2.2000000e+00, 2.3476000e+00,
       2.6386000e+00, 3.0332000e+00, 3.4218000e+00, 4.0000000e+00,
       4.0000000e+00, 4.0000000e+00, 4.0500000e+00, 4.1000000e+00,
       4.1500000e+00, 4.2978000e+00, 4.6630000e+00, 5.1240000e+00,
       5.6640000e+00, 6.0000000e+00, 6.0500000e+00, 6.1500000e+00,
       6.4658000e+00, 7.0000000e+00, 7.4410000e+00, 8.0000000e+00,
       8.1000000e+00, 8.3500000e+00, 8.9414000e+00, 9.4960000e+00,
       1.0031600e+01, 1.0291000e+01, 1.0933500e+01, 1.1585100e+01,
       1.2100000e+01, 1.2735700e+01, 1.3531200e+01, 1.4169500e+01,
       1.5000000e+01, 1.5985300e+01, 1.6753900e+01, 1.7894500e+01,
       1.8880200e+01, 2.0076900e+01, 2.1259500e+01, 2.2545500e+01,
       2.4053700e+01, 2.5606200e+01, 2.7227700e+01, 2.9049800e+01,
       3.1036700e+01, 3.3092700e+01, 3.5307800e+01, 3.7707200e+01,
       4.0306600e+01, 4.3051700e+01, 4.5969700e+01, 4.9029100e+01,
       5.2323200e+01, 5.5997000e+01, 5.9875500e+01, 6.4000000e+01,
       6.8299200e+01, 7.3040000e+01, 7.8102900e+01, 8.3400000e+01,
       8.8983700e+01, 9.5201100e+01, 1.0167750e+02, 1.0873550e+02,
       1.1608100e+02, 1.2402830e+02, 1.3227530e+02, 1.4071130e+02,
       1.5020780e+02, 1.6034020e+02, 1.7100620e+02, 1.8246580e+02,
       1.9532960e+02, 2.0884600e+02, 2.2325970e+02, 2.3874330e+02,
       2.5563800e+02, 2.7392080e+02, 2.9362100e+02, 3.1453630e+02,
       3.3796300e+02, 3.6373040e+02, 3.9154620e+02, 4.2200780e+02,
       4.5533300e+02, 4.9321970e+02, 5.3590330e+02, 5.8393730e+02,
       6.4024060e+02, 7.0435050e+02, 7.8055390e+02, 8.7628510e+02,
       9.9769820e+02, 1.1596923e+03, 1.4036132e+03, 1.8536339e+03,
       3.2332685e+03]
```

Comment: There's something wrong with the underlying math model here related to the `limit`.  I should have called it out earlier on your first post.  The variable here is just a binary indicator to say if each factory (or machine) produces one type of product.  There is no accounting in your model anywhere for the number of things produced...?  If 2 of the 5 factories produce 'A', you say the limit is 2x60=120.  120 what?  Are you saying that if they produce 121 of product 'A' that the penalty is incurred?

Comment: yes - the echarge_a of 0.007 will apply to the 121st product. 
Testing indicates the maths to be correct in the above pulp....

Comment: I’m not sure I agree that the math is correct.  Using your small data set (which is nice for testing, etc.), where do you see the quantity produced?  What would motivate production (there is no demand signal)?

Comment: You will end up with multiple millions of binary variables. That often means we need to use expensive commercial MIP solvers (and beefy machines).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen The model is not properly constructed.  There is no quantity represented.  Right now, the dimensionality of the binary decision variable covering which product to produce is `make[f, p]` which is only `|f| x |p|` ~ 200 x 2.  ... waiting on follow-up regarding quantity is intended to be handled from OP.

Comment: "Ideally I'd like to be able to solve this problem for ~1million factories (industrial units)." So with two products, we have 2 million binary variables. (Of course a correct model is way better than an incorrect one, but this count is not depending on that).

Comment: The quantity produced / demand signal is irrelevant as I can't optimise/allocate the production between 'factories'  - how they get used is effectively out of my control however the emissions production can be optimised (this problem). 

I have tested the pulp implementation above with several subsets - the maths does work as expected. 

Yep, millions of binary variables, and it does seem gurobi is expensive... 

I have wondered if there is a better approach, e.g I did get ok results using scipy minimise, but that was a fairly restrictive/inflexible implementation (not pulp)