# Optimization with a nested set of constraints

Tags: python, gekko

I am trying to use Gekko to find an optimal solution for a camera lens distortion calibration problem ([Undistort](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga7dfb72c9cf9780a347fbe3d1c47e5d5a)). In my case I am interested in solving a simpler problem that is only concerned with determining two or four variables (K1 K2 || K1 K2 CX CY). I was able to use scipy.optimize.minimize to come to some reasonable solutions that I know are within a good range, however, my solution relies on a rather complex invertibility constraint of the final result and I found that this was not possible to implement in scipy. So, I am looking for some help on how to model this invertibility constraint using Gekko.

The invertibility constraint is as follows ( see div_constraint_invertibility() ):

```
def get_rad_norm_k(dc, w, h):
      dmi = get_max_dist(dc=dc, w=w, h=h)
      r2 = m.sqrt(dmi) / 2
      r2_2 = r2*r2
      r2_4 = r2_2*r2_2
      denk1 = -12 * r2_2
      denk2 = -12 * r2_4
      return denk1, denk2
```

```
def get_max_dist(dc, h, w):
    corner_distances = [(dc[0] - 0)**2 + (dc[1] - 0)**2,
                        (dc[0] - 0)**2 + (dc[1] - w)**2,
                        (dc[0] - h)**2 + (dc[1] - w)**2,
                        (dc[0] - h)**2 + (dc[1] - 0)**2]

    mx = corner_distances[0]
    for cd in corner_distances[1:]:
        mx = m.max3(mx, cd)
    return mx
```

```
def div_constraint_invertibility(x, ldm):

    p1 = x[0]
    p2 = x[1]
    dc = [ldm.Cx, ldm.Cy]
    
    w = ldm.width
    h = ldm.height
    denk1, denk2 = get_rad_norm_k(dc=dc, w=w, h=h)
    
    r1sq = get_max_dist(dc=dc, w=w, h=h)
    r1p4 = r1sq**2
    
    k1 = (((-p1) / (1 + p1)) + ((16 * p2) / (1 + p2))) / denk1
    k2 = (((-4 * p2) / (1 + p2)) + (p1 / (1 + p1))) / denk2
    
    if -2 < r1sq * k1 < 2:
        if -1. - r1sq * k1 < r1p4 * k2 < (1. - r1sq * k1) / 3:
            return 1  # Passed Check
    else:
        if r1sq * k1 >= 2:
            if -1. - r1sq * k1 < r1p4 * k2 < (-r1p4 * k1**2 / 12):
                return 1  # Passed Check
    
    return -1  # Failed Check
```

The list of values in argument x contains [P1, P2] or [P1, P2, CX, CY] where P1 and P2 are normalized values of K1 and K2.
I have tried to implement the methods using Gekko functions, my next step was to try to implement the conditional checks in "div_constraint_invertibility" using m.if3(). Although, I am wondering if there is a better way to format the problem here as I feel that such a nested m.if3() structure is not a very elegant solution and moreover I am not certain what I should actually return from the function (I probably should be returning some function value rather than -1 or 1...).

**EDIT 1**
Scipy entry point and other contextual code.
Here is the scipy minimization approach. The function cumulative_point_to_line_error takes a set of points belonging to an arc extracted from a distorted image and applies the distortion model to determine the line equation fit error after undistorting the image points. An initial starting point looks something like:

```
dm0 = [-0.0, 0.0, input_image_center_X, input_image_center_Y]
```

Along with an array of points that correspond to an arc. For example, depending on the image there may be 30 lists containing sets of points relating to the same extracted arc.

I can provide even more code but wanted to avoid dumping a wall of code...let me know and I can dm you it or I can provide more code here too.

```
def model_estimation(ip, w, h, oc):
    ldm = ip.lens_model
    dc = [ldm.Cx, ldm.Cy]
    prevk1 = ldm.d[1]

    if len(ldm.d) != 3:
        ldm.d.append(0)
    prevk2 = ldm.d[2]
    if oc:
        dm0 = [prevp1, prevp2, dc[0], dc[1]]
    else:
        dm0 = [prevp1, prevp2]

    cons = []
    bnds = []
    if oc:
        dc_drift = 2
        bnds = [(-np.inf, np.inf), (-np.inf, np.inf),
                (float(ldm.width / 2 - dc_drift), float(ldm.width / 2 + dc_drift)),
                (float(ldm.height / 2 - dc_drift), float(ldm.height / 2 + dc_drift))]

    cons.append({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': div_constraint_invertibility, 'args': (ip.lens_model,)})

    print(f"Optimizing: {dm0}")
    if cons:
        print(f"Constraints:")
        for con in cons:
            print(f"Const: {con['fun'].__name__}")
    if bnds:
        print(f"Bounds:")
        for idx, bnd in enumerate(bnds):
            print(f"{bnd[0]} <= x{idx} <= {bnd[1]}")

    result = spo.minimize(fun=cumulative_point_to_line_error, x0=np.array(dm0), args=(ip,),
                          constraints=cons, bounds=bnds, method='SLSQP', options={"disp": True})

    print(f"Optimization Result: {result.x} | {result.fun}")
```

**EDIT 2**

I gave it a shot trying to convert my objective to one that is useable with Gekko. Is is possible to call m.Minimize on something like 'cumulative_point_to_line_error'? Currently working on how to handle the division by 0 check in the 'div_update_point' method as well as the if statements in 'dist_points_to_equation':

```
def dist_points_to_equation(m, k1, k2, dc_x, dc_y, hl: Line):
pnts_o = hl.pnts
err = 0
zero = 10e-100
num_pnts = len(pnts_o)
um = vm = 0
suu = suv = svv = 0

pnts_e = []
for pnt in pnts_o:
    x, y = div_update_point(m=m, px=pnt[0], py=pnt[1], K1=k1, K2=k2, dc_x=dc_x, dc_y=dc_y)
    pnts_e.append([x, y])

for pnt in pnts_e:
    x = pnt[0]
    y = pnt[1]
    um += x
    vm += y
um = um / num_pnts
vm = vm / num_pnts

for pnt in pnts_e:
    x = pnt[0]
    y = pnt[1]
    suu += (x - um) ** 2
    suv += (x - um) * (y - vm)
    svv += (y - vm) ** 2
suu = suu / num_pnts
suv = suv / num_pnts
svv = svv / num_pnts

if np.abs(suv) <= zero:
    # print('XY <= ZERO*')
    if suu < svv and svv > zero:
        hl.a = 1.
        hl.b = 0.
        hl.c = -um
        err = 0.
        # print(f'Iter. Method Line: {self.a}x + {self.b}y + {self.c} = 0')
        # print(f'Error == {err}')
        return hl, err
    if svv < suu and suu > zero:
        hl.a = 0.
        hl.b = 1.
        hl.c = -vm
        err = 0
        # print(f'Iter. Method Line: {self.a}x + {self.b}y + {self.c} = 0')
        # print(f'Error == {err}')
        return hl, err
    # print('Failed to recalculate!')
    return None, err

r = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 0]], dtype=float)

h = 0.5 * (suu - svv) / suv
if h > 0:
    r[0, 1] = -h - np.sqrt(1. + np.square(h))
    r[0, 2] = -(um + r[0, 1] * vm)
    r[1, 1] = -1. / r[0, 1]
    r[1, 2] = -(um + r[1, 1] * vm)
    r[2, 0] = h + np.sqrt(1. + np.square(h))
    r[2, 2] = -(r[2, 0] * um + vm)
    r[3, 0] = -1. / r[2, 0]
    r[3, 2] = -(r[3, 0] * um + vm)
else:
    r[0, 1] = -h + np.sqrt(1. + np.square(h))
    r[0, 2] = -(um + r[0, 1] * vm)
    r[1, 1] = -1. / r[0, 1]
    r[1, 2] = -(um + r[1, 1] * vm)
    r[2, 0] = h - np.sqrt(1. + np.square(h))
    r[2, 2] = -(r[2, 0] * um + vm)
    r[3, 0] = -1. / r[2, 0]
    r[3, 2] = -(r[3, 0] * um + vm)

for row in range(0, r.shape[0]):
    norm = np.sqrt(np.square(r[row, 0]) + np.square(r[row, 1]))
    for col in range(0, r.shape[1]):
        r[row, col] /= norm

min_err = 0
k = 0
for pnt in pnts_e:
    x = pnt[0]
    y = pnt[1]
    sol = r[0, 0] * x + r[0, 1] * y + r[0, 2]
    min_err += np.square(sol)

for row in range(1, r.shape[0]):
    h = 0
    for pnt in pnts_e:
        x = pnt[0]
        y = pnt[1]
        sol = r[row, 0] * x + r[row, 1] * y + r[row, 2]
        h += np.square(sol)
    if h < min_err:
        k = row
        min_err = h

hl.a = r[k, 0]
hl.b = r[k, 1]
hl.c = r[k, 2]
# err = min_err / num_pnts
# print(min_err, num_pnts)
# print(err)

return hl, min_err


def cumulative_point_to_line_error(m, p1, p2, dc_x, dc_y, w, h, houghlines):

    denk1, denk2 = get_rad_norm_k(m, dc_x=dc_x, dc_y=dc_y, w=w, h=h)

    k1 = m.Intermediate(((-p1) / (1 + p1)) + (16 * p2 / (1 + p2))/denk1)
    k2 = m.Intermediate(((-4 * p2) / (1 + p2)) + (p1 / (1 + p1))/denk2)

    cumulative_err = 0
    for idx, hl in enumerate(houghlines):
        new_hl, err = dist_points_to_equation(m, k1, k2, dc_x, dc_y, hl)
        houghlines[idx] = new_hl
        cumulative_err += err
    return cumulative_err
```

Comment: Scipy certainly can accept your invertibility function, though it isn't going to work very well unless you convert the hard 1/-1 into continuous discrimination values.

Comment: How could this be impemented in scipy, from my readings it seemed that scipy minimize can't work with if statements (some comments on the topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71329868/how-to-define-conditional-constraints-in-optimization-utilizing-scipy-minimize)

Comment: I could demonstrate, but there is not enough contextual code for this to be reproducible. Show your scipy entry point and some realistic estimate parameters.

Comment: @Reinderien I added some more context relating to the scipy entry point. Let me know if you need more, I can provide the code in a better format over DM too if you'd like.

Comment: When is `oc` true? If it is, the narrowed bounds seem very incompatible with your invertibility constraint.

Comment: @Reinderien I made another edit if that helps contextualize things a bit more, sorry there is just a lot of code. oc is true when the distortion center should be optimized along with the distortion coefficients.

Comment: I'm unclear on how that answers the question. That's a whole lot of code that does not at all mention `oc`.

Comment: I was referring to how I’ve added more detail regarding what exactly I’m trying to minimize. In edit 1 the usage of oc is shown. The parameter oc is just a flag that either passes the distortion coefficients and the distortion center (x, y), or just the distortion coefficients, as values to optimize. These are passed to scipy minimize in the argument x0.

Comment: Thanks for asking another follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77881978/modelling-objective-function-for-distortion-parameter-optimization  I'm including the link for those who are following this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample code with the conditional statements to determine the upper limit for `r1p4 * k2` based on whether it is less than or greater than 2.

```py
    # Implementing the conditional upper constraints
    c1 = m.if3(r1sq * k1-2,1,0)
    m.Equation(r1p4 * k2 < c1    * ((1 - r1sq * k1) / 3) \
                         + (1-c1)* (-r1p4 * k1**2 / 12))
```

The lower limit is always the same, so there is no change in that equation:

```py
    # Lower constraint always the same
    m.Equation(r1p4 * k2 > -1 - r1sq * k1)
```

Also, the objective function should be adjusted for some form of distortion measure. A simple objective is currently used in this example with `m.Minimize(P1**2 + P2**2)` that likely needs to be adjusted. Here is a complete example script that needs to be adjusted with the objective function and checked for the correct constraints.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import math

# Initialize Gekko Model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Define constants
ldm_width = 100   # width
ldm_height = 100  # height
dc_drift = 10

# Define variables
P1 = m.Var()
P2 = m.Var()
CX = m.Var(lb=ldm_width/2-dc_drift,ub=ldm_width/2+dc_drift)
CY = m.Var(lb=ldm_width/2-dc_drift,ub=ldm_width/2+dc_drift)

# Calculate maximum distance
def get_max_dist(m, dc_x, dc_y, w, h):
    corner_distances = [m.sqrt((dc_x - 0)**2 + (dc_y - 0)**2),
                        m.sqrt((dc_x - 0)**2 + (dc_y - w)**2),
                        m.sqrt((dc_x - h)**2 + (dc_y - w)**2),
                        m.sqrt((dc_x - h)**2 + (dc_y - 0)**2)]
    # m.max3() only compares two values
    # create 3 m.max3() functions to compare 4 values
    mx1 = m.max3(corner_distances[0],corner_distances[1])
    mx2 = m.max3(corner_distances[2],corner_distances[3])    
    return m.max3(mx1,mx2)
    
def get_rad_norm_k(m, dc_x, dc_y, w, h):
    # Calculate the maximum distance
    dmi = get_max_dist(m, dc_x, dc_y, w, h)

    # Calculate r2, r2_2, and r2_4
    r2 = m.sqrt(dmi) / 2
    r2_2 = m.Intermediate(r2 * r2)
    r2_4 = m.Intermediate(r2_2 * r2_2)

    # Calculate denk1 and denk2
    denk1 = m.Intermediate(-12 * r2_2)
    denk2 = m.Intermediate(-12 * r2_4)
    return denk1, denk2

# Constraint function
def div_constraint_invertibility(m, p1, p2, dc_x, dc_y, w, h):
    denk1, denk2 = get_rad_norm_k(m, dc_x, dc_y, w, h)

    r1sq = get_max_dist(m, dc_x, dc_y, w, h)
    r1p4 = r1sq**2

    k1 = m.Intermediate((((-p1) / (1 + p1)) + ((16 * p2) / (1 + p2))) / denk1)
    k2 = m.Intermediate((((-4 * p2) / (1 + p2)) + (p1 / (1 + p1))) / denk2)

    # Lower constraint always the same
    m.Equation(r1p4 * k2 > -1 - r1sq * k1)

    # Implementing the conditional upper constraints
    c1 = m.if3(r1sq * k1-2,1,0) # c1=1 if r1sq * k1<2
                                # c1=0 if r1sq * k1>=2
    m.Equation(r1p4 * k2 < c1    * ((1 - r1sq * k1) / 3) \
                         + (1-c1)* (-r1p4 * k1**2 / 12))
    return

# Call constraint function
div_constraint_invertibility(m, P1, P2, CX, CY, ldm_width, ldm_height)

# Define objective function
# May want to minimize some form of distortion measure
# For demonstration, a dummy objective function:
m.Minimize(P1**2 + P2**2)

# Solve the problem
m.solve(disp=True)
print("P1:", P1.value[0])
print("P2:", P2.value[0])
print("CX:", CX.value[0])
print("CY:", CY.value[0])
```

It gives a solution:

```
 Number of state variables:    34
 Number of total equations: -  23
 Number of slack variables: -  16
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    -5

 * Warning: DOF <= 0
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    7 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    2 Obj:  7.43E-02 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:   7.43E-02 Lowest Leaf:   7.43E-02 Gap:   3.19E-16
Iter:     2 I:  0 Tm:     -0.00 NLPi:    2 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj:  7.43E-02 Gap:  3.19E-16
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.020000000000000004 sec
 Objective      :  0.07430032944477045
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------


P1: 0.0088558263617
P2: -0.27243697213
CX: 50.0
CY: 50.0
```

Comment: Hey John, thanks so much for this! I am working on making some edits to my code to use Gekko (it's a really great tool!) Could something like what I've added with my second edit be translated into a Gekko style Objective function? Here I am essentially taking the current model of distortion and seeing how well it does at undistorting the extracted arcs and fitting the points to a line equation. Ideally, minimizing the cumulative error should provide the best model for undistortion.

Comment: With only part of the code, it is difficult to suggest something that would work. I recommend that you try to get it as close as you can and then ask another question on StackOverflow with the `gekko` code. The one recommendation from Edit 2 is to try `h + m.sign3(h)*m.sqrt(1. + h**2)` to get the positive or negative sign that you need instead of the `if` statement. Generative AI can also give suggestions and help pick out syntax errors.

Comment: @JohnHedengren While that may be true in theory, keep in mind that [all use of generative AI is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned). Also, in practice, I would never recommend AI as a substitute for actual learning.

Comment: @Reinderien - you are correct that Generative AI should not be used on StackOverflow because that is how the models are trained, and it is against the community policy. We've all heard that 40% of code on GitHub was AI generated in June 2023 - projections are that 80% of code will be AI generated in 5 years. I don't use Copilot, but I've heard impressive stats especially for beginning programmers. We'll keep StackOverflow clean, but beginner programmers have a great tool to help them develop code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to call it here and show you what I have so far, with the knowledge that it will need modification to suit "what you're actually doing". This use scipy, which - as I understand it - you were trying to use originally.

The gist is that you want all of your constraint operations to be continuous. It would be nice if they were differentiable as well, and in this demonstration they are not; making them differentiable would be somewhat challenging given what you're trying to do. This demonstration shows a continuous cosine windowing function applied to the centre constraint. (Given the numbers at play, the upper constraint is not relevant, but would follow the same pattern of a left-handed window function). To the exterior of the window function, apply a simple linear operation to your `r1sq*k1` that tells the optimizer that the further away it gets from -2 through 2, the safer it is. This is again continuous because it's been set to 0 where the windowing function is also zero.

```py
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, Bounds, NonlinearConstraint


def get_rad_norm_k(dmi: float) -> tuple[float, float]:
    r2 = 0.5*np.sqrt(dmi)
    r2_2 = r2**2
    r2_4 = r2_2**2
    denk1 = -12*r2_2
    denk2 = -12*r2_4
    return denk1, denk2


def get_dists(dc_x: float, dc_y: float, w: float, h: float) -> float:
    corners = np.linalg.norm(
        (
            (dc_x, dc_y),
            (dc_x, dc_y - w),
            (dc_x - h, dc_y - w),
            (dc_x - h, dc_y),
        ),
        axis=1,
    )
    return corners.max()


def constraint_shared(params: np.ndarray, w: float, h: float) -> tuple[
    float, float, float, float,
]:
    p1, p2, dc_x, dc_y = params
    r1sq = get_dists(dc_x, dc_y, w, h)
    denk1, denk2 = get_rad_norm_k(dmi=r1sq)
    r1p4 = r1sq**2

    k1 = (-p1/(1 + p1) + 16*p2/(1 + p2))/denk1
    k2 = (-4*p2/(1 + p2) + p1/(1 + p1))/denk2

    return r1p4, r1sq, k1, k2


def constraint_lower(params: np.ndarray, w: float, h: float) -> float:
    r1p4, r1sq, k1, k2 = constraint_shared(params, w, h)
    # -2 < r1sq * k1
    evaluated = r1sq * k1
    return evaluated


def constraint_mid(params: np.ndarray, w: float, h: float) -> tuple[float, float]:
    r1p4, r1sq, k1, k2 = constraint_shared(params, w, h)

    # if -2 < r1sq * k1 < 2:
    cond = r1sq * k1

    if cond <= -2:
        # Linear increase away from zero as condition number goes negative
        return -2 - cond, cond - -2
    if cond >= 2:
        # Linear increase away from zero as condition number goes positive
        return cond - 2, 2 - cond

    # Continuous window: y=0 at -2 and +2; y=1 at 0; dy/dx=0 at -2, 0 and +2.
    window = 0.5 + 0.5*np.cos(0.5*np.pi*cond)

    check = r1p4*k2

    # if -1. - r1sq * k1 < r1p4 * k2:
    #     return 1  # Passed Check
    lower = (check - (-1 - cond))*window

    # if r1p4 * k2 < (1. - r1sq * k1) / 3:
    #     return 1  # Passed Check
    upper = (check - (1 - cond)/3)*window

    # Sanity check; delete me
    fits_low = -1. - r1sq * k1 < r1p4 * k2
    fits_high = r1p4 * k2 < (1. - r1sq * k1) / 3
    assert fits_low == (lower >= 0)
    assert fits_high == (upper <= 0)

    return lower, upper


def objective(param: np.ndarray) -> float:
    p = param[:2]
    # Negative instead of positive for more interesting constraint usage
    return -p.dot(p)


def main() -> None:
    ldm_width = 100
    ldm_height = 100
    dc_drift = 10

    result = minimize(
        fun=objective,
        x0=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5*ldm_width, 0.5*ldm_height),
        bounds=Bounds(
            lb=(0, 0, -np.inf, -np.inf),
            # These are the bounds from 'oc' mode, omitted here because they are infeasible.
            # lb=(ldm_width/2 - dc_drift, ldm_width/2 - dc_drift, -np.inf, -np.inf),
            ub=(ldm_width/2 + dc_drift, ldm_width/2 + dc_drift, +np.inf, +np.inf),
        ),
        constraints=(
            NonlinearConstraint(
                fun=partial(constraint_lower, w=ldm_width, h=ldm_height),
                lb=-2, ub=np.inf,
            ),
            NonlinearConstraint(
                fun=partial(constraint_mid, w=ldm_width, h=ldm_height),
                lb=(0, -np.inf),
                ub=(np.inf, 0),
            ),
        ),
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)
    p1, p2, dc_x, dc_y = result.x

    print(f'obj = {result.fun:.3f}')
    print(f'p = {p1:.3f}, {p2:.3f}')
    print(f'dc = {dc_x:.3f}, {dc_y:.3f}')

    lower = constraint_lower(result.x, ldm_width, ldm_height)
    print(f'Lower constraint evaluates to -2 <= {lower:.3f}')

    r1p4, r1sq, k1, k2 = constraint_shared(params=result.x, w=ldm_width, h=ldm_height)
    cond = r1sq*k1
    print(f'Mid predicate evaluates to -2 <= {cond:.3f} <= 2')
    if -2 < cond < 2:
        print(f'    Constraint: {-1 - r1sq*k1:.3f} <= {r1p4*k2:.3f} <= {(1 - r1sq*k1)/3:.3f}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
obj = -3600.578
p = 60.000, 0.760
dc = 50.000, 50.000
Lower constraint evaluates to -2 <= -1.975
Mid predicate evaluates to -2 <= -1.975 <= 2
    Constraint: 0.975 <= 0.992 <= 0.992
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful! I looked around quite a bit before posting this question and couldn't find anything related to handling constraints of this form with scipy. Do you know of any resources you could share?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Agnostic from scipy/Gekko, if you want to learn more about the theory of conditional constraints, I suggest that you post on Operations Research where there is much more focused analytic-theoretic expertise.