# Modelling Objective Function for Distortion Parameter Optimization

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am trying to use Python Gekko to optimize a set of distortion parameters for a camera given a single image (I am not trying to perform pattern based calibration, the image below is just a test example). My code initially applies some edge detection (Canny), then filtering processes to extract Hough Lines (long continuous arcs of x,y points in the input image), and finally it selects an initial guess of the distortion by determining coefficients that best transform the arcs (sets of points) to straight lines. This final step is performed by taking the input set of detected points and using a least squares approach to select the best form of the line equation: `Ax + By + C = 0`, the standard form is used to better model vertical lines.

This pictures shows points belonging to the same arc (some of the colours are very similar, however, they are infact identified as seperate arcs).

[image]

My goal is to then take the set of detected arcs (In Python of the form: `List [ List [ [ float , float ], ... ], ... ]` ) and optimize the parameters `K1, K2, Cx, Cy`. An example starting point for this image is: `K1 = -0.0, K2 = 0.0, Cx = 160, Cy = 120`, where the image size is `W = 320 H = 240`. At the bottom of this post I added some example data for the arcs as it takes up a lot of space.

In my code I have it so that the user can decide whether or not to try optimizing Cx and Cy. For this post we can just assume the we are optimizing Cx and Cy. Initially I had an objective function which I wanted to minimize using scipy and it seemed to work fine, however, since Gekko requires a different format/layout I'm not certain what the best way is to set this objective function up.

My method for determining the undistortion error takes in the set of distortion variables `K1, K2, Cx, Cy` along with the sets of points belonging to the extracted arcs.

1. Horner polynomial evaluation is used to determine each points undistorted position (This could also be replaced with the symbolic equation (which I assume Gekko would prefer, however it may need to handle potential division by zero in A):

```py
A = 1 / (1 + (k1)*(r)^2 + (k2)*(r)^4)
x_u = Cx + (x_d - Cx) * A
y_u = Cy + (y_d - Cy) * A
```

2. Least squares approach is applied to the undistorted points to determine a line of best fit `Ax + By + C = 0`
3. The points are evaluated relative to the line equation to determine the sum of the squared error

The theory is that the optimal distortion model should transform the extracted arcs to straight lines.

Here is my code so far, this was initially based on scipy- and after reading up on Gekko I think that it will require some significant changes to implement so I wanted to reach out for some help.

```
def HornerPoly(poly, n, nrmx):
    sol = poly[n]
    i = n - 1
    while i > -1:
        sol = sol * nrmx + poly[i]
        i -= 1
    return sol


def div_update_point(m, px, py, K1, K2, dc_x, dc_y):
    center_dist = (px - dc_x)**2 + (py - dc_y)**2
    dist_coef = [1, K1, K2]
    A = HornerPoly(dist_coef, len(dist_coef) - 1, center_dist)

    # slack = m.Var(lb=0, ...)
    # m.Equation(slack...)
    # m.IF ?
    if A == 0:
        return px, py
    else:
        A = 1.0 / A

    new_x = dc_x + (px - dc_x) * A
    new_y = dc_y + (py - dc_y) * A
    return new_x, new_y


def get_rad_norm_k(m, dc_x, dc_y, w, h):
    # Calculate the maximum distance
    dmi = get_max_dist(m, dc_x, dc_y, w, h)

    # Calculate r2, r2_2, and r2_4
    r2 = m.sqrt(dmi) / 2
    r2_2 = m.Intermediate(r2 * r2)
    r2_4 = m.Intermediate(r2_2 * r2_2)

    # Calculate denk1 and denk2
    denk1 = m.Intermediate(-12 * r2_2)
    denk2 = m.Intermediate(-12 * r2_4)
    return denk1, denk2


def get_max_dist(m, dc_x, dc_y, w, h):
    corner_distances = [(dc_x - 0)**2 + (dc_y - 0)**2,
                        (dc_x - 0)**2 + (dc_y - w)**2,
                        (dc_x - h)**2 + (dc_y - w)**2,
                        (dc_x - h)**2 + (dc_y - 0)**2]
    # m.max3() only compares two values
    # create 3 m.max3() functions to compare 4 values
    mx1 = m.max3(corner_distances[0], corner_distances[1])
    mx2 = m.max3(corner_distances[2], corner_distances[3])
    return m.max3(mx1, mx2)


def dist_points_to_equation(m, k1, k2, dc_x, dc_y, hl: Line):
    pnts_o = hl.pnts
    err = 0
    zero = 10e-100
    num_pnts = len(pnts_o)
    um = vm = 0
    suu = suv = svv = 0
    
    # Transform the distorted points to the undistorted points given the lens model
    pnts_e = []
    for pnt in pnts_o:
        x, y = div_update_point(m=m, px=pnt[0], py=pnt[1], K1=k1, K2=k2, dc_x=dc_x, dc_y=dc_y)
        pnts_e.append([x, y])
    
    # Get avg. x, y
    for pnt in pnts_e:
        x = pnt[0]
        y = pnt[1]
        um += x
        vm += y
    um = um / num_pnts
    vm = vm / num_pnts
    
    # Get avg. sum of squares xx, xy, yy
    for pnt in pnts_e:
        x = pnt[0]
        y = pnt[1]
        suu += (x - um) ** 2
        suv += (x - um) * (y - vm)
        svv += (y - vm) ** 2
    suu = suu / num_pnts
    suv = suv / num_pnts
    svv = svv / num_pnts

    # Check perfectly horizontal or vertical
    if np.abs(suv) <= zero:
        # print('XY <= ZERO*')
        if suu < svv and svv > zero:
            hl.a = 1.
            hl.b = 0.
            hl.c = -um
            err = 0.
            # print(f'Iter. Method Line: {self.a}x + {self.b}y + {self.c} = 0')
            # print(f'Error == {err}')
            return hl, err
        if svv < suu and suu > zero:
            hl.a = 0.
            hl.b = 1.
            hl.c = -vm
            err = 0
            # print(f'Iter. Method Line: {self.a}x + {self.b}y + {self.c} = 0')
            # print(f'Error == {err}')
            return hl, err
        # print('Failed to recalculate!')
        return None, err
    
    # Initialize system
    r = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                  [1, 0, 0],
                  [0, 1, 0],
                  [0, 1, 0]], dtype=float)

    h = 0.5 * (suu - svv) / suv
    # Note: Can add m.sin here to simplify
    if h > 0:
        r[0, 1] = -h - np.sqrt(1. + np.square(h))
        r[0, 2] = -(um + r[0, 1] * vm)
        r[1, 1] = -1. / r[0, 1]
        r[1, 2] = -(um + r[1, 1] * vm)
        r[2, 0] = h + np.sqrt(1. + np.square(h))
        r[2, 2] = -(r[2, 0] * um + vm)
        r[3, 0] = -1. / r[2, 0]
        r[3, 2] = -(r[3, 0] * um + vm)
    else:
        r[0, 1] = -h + np.sqrt(1. + np.square(h))
        r[0, 2] = -(um + r[0, 1] * vm)
        r[1, 1] = -1. / r[0, 1]
        r[1, 2] = -(um + r[1, 1] * vm)
        r[2, 0] = h - np.sqrt(1. + np.square(h))
        r[2, 2] = -(r[2, 0] * um + vm)
        r[3, 0] = -1. / r[2, 0]
        r[3, 2] = -(r[3, 0] * um + vm)
    
    for row in range(0, r.shape[0]):
        norm = np.sqrt(np.square(r[row, 0]) + np.square(r[row, 1]))
        for col in range(0, r.shape[1]):
            r[row, col] /= norm

    min = 0
    k = 0
    # Get squared error of the undistorted points with the line equations
    for pnt in pnts_e:
        x = pnt[0]
        y = pnt[1]
        sol = r[0, 0] * x + r[0, 1] * y + r[0, 2]
        min += np.square(sol)
    
    # Select the lowest squared error
    for row in range(1, r.shape[0]):
        h = 0
        for pnt in pnts_e:
            x = pnt[0]
            y = pnt[1]
            sol = r[row, 0] * x + r[row, 1] * y + r[row, 2]
            h += np.square(sol)
        if h < min:
            k = row
            min = h

    hl.a = r[k, 0]
    hl.b = r[k, 1]
    hl.c = r[k, 2]
    # err = min / num_pnts
    # print(min, num_pnts)
    # print(err)

    return hl, min


def cumulative_point_to_line_error(m, p1, p2, dc_x, dc_y, w, h, houghlines):

    n1 = m.Intermediate(((-p1) / (1 + p1)) + (16 * p2 / (1 + p2)))
    n2 = m.Intermediate(((-4 * p2) / (1 + p2)) + (p1 / (1 + p1)))
    denk1, denk2 = get_rad_norm_k(m, dc_x=dc_x, dc_y=dc_y, w=w, h=h)

    k1 = m.Intermediate(n1/denk1)
    k2 = m.Intermediate(n2/denk2)

    cumulative_err = 0
    for idx, hl in enumerate(houghlines):
        new_hl, err = dist_points_to_equation(m, k1, k2, dc_x, dc_y, hl)
        houghlines[idx] = new_hl
        cumulative_err += err
    return cumulative_err


def ldm_solver(ip: HoughLineSet, dc_drift=10, opt_dc=False):

    ldm: LensDistortionModel = ip.lens_model  # The lens model used to extract the set of arcs

    m = GEKKO(remote=False)

    ldm_w = ldm.width  # ex. 320
    ldm_h = ldm.height  # ex. 240

    P1 = m.Var()
    P2 = m.Var()

    if opt_dc:  # optimize distortion center?
        CX = m.Var(lb=ldm_w / 2 - dc_drift, ub=ldm_w / 2 + dc_drift)
        CY = m.Var(lb=ldm_h / 2 - dc_drift, ub=ldm_h / 2 + dc_drift)
    else:
        CX = m.Const(value=ldm_w/2)
        CY = m.Const(value=ldm_h/2)

    # Add invertibility constraint to system?
    # div_constraint_invertibility(m, p1=P1, p2=P2, dc_x=CX, dc_y=CY, w=ldm_w, h=ldm_h)

    # What to pass here to minimize/or objective?
    # m.Obj...
    m.Minimize(cumulative_point_to_line_error(m=m, p1=P1, p2=P2, dc_x=CX, dc_y=CY,
                                              w=ldm_w, h=ldm_h, houghlines=ip.lines))

    m.solve(disp=True)
    print("P1:", P1.value[0])
    print("P2:", P2.value[0])
    print("CX:", CX.value[0])
    print("CY:", CY.value[0])
```

---

**Here is an example list of 5 arcs with their points:**

Arc0:

`[[161.0, 2.0], [161.0, 3.0], [160.0, 8.0], [160.0, 9.0], [160.0, 10.0], [160.0, 11.0], [160.0, 12.0], [160.0, 13.0], [160.0, 14.0], [159.0, 26.0], [159.0, 27.0], [159.0, 28.0], [159.0, 29.0], [159.0, 30.0], [159.0, 31.0], [159.0, 32.0], [159.0, 33.0], [159.0, 34.0], [159.0, 35.0], [159.0, 36.0], [159.0, 37.0], [159.0, 38.0], [159.0, 39.0], [159.0, 40.0], [158.0, 45.0], [158.0, 46.0], [158.0, 47.0], [158.0, 48.0], [158.0, 49.0], [158.0, 50.0], [158.0, 51.0], [158.0, 52.0], [158.0, 53.0], [158.0, 54.0], [158.0, 55.0], [158.0, 56.0], [158.0, 57.0], [158.0, 58.0], [158.0, 59.0], [158.0, 60.0], [158.0, 61.0], [158.0, 62.0], [158.0, 63.0], [158.0, 64.0], [158.0, 65.0], [157.0, 68.0], [157.0, 80.0], [157.0, 81.0], [157.0, 82.0], [157.0, 83.0], [157.0, 84.0], [157.0, 85.0], [157.0, 86.0], [157.0, 87.0], [157.0, 88.0], [157.0, 89.0], [157.0, 90.0], [157.0, 91.0], [157.0, 92.0], [157.0, 93.0], [157.0, 94.0], [157.0, 95.0], [157.0, 96.0], [157.0, 97.0], [157.0, 98.0], [157.0, 99.0], [157.0, 100.0], [157.0, 101.0], [157.0, 102.0], [156.0, 107.0], [156.0, 108.0], [156.0, 109.0], [156.0, 110.0], [156.0, 111.0], [156.0, 112.0], [156.0, 113.0], [156.0, 114.0], [156.0, 115.0], [156.0, 116.0], [156.0, 117.0], [156.0, 118.0], [156.0, 119.0], [156.0, 120.0], [156.0, 121.0], [156.0, 122.0], [156.0, 123.0], [156.0, 124.0], [156.0, 125.0], [156.0, 126.0], [156.0, 127.0], [156.0, 128.0], [156.0, 129.0], [155.0, 141.0], [155.0, 142.0], [155.0, 143.0], [155.0, 144.0], [155.0, 145.0], [155.0, 146.0], [155.0, 147.0], [155.0, 148.0], [155.0, 149.0], [155.0, 150.0], [155.0, 151.0], [155.0, 152.0], [155.0, 153.0], [155.0, 154.0], [155.0, 155.0], [155.0, 156.0], [155.0, 157.0], [155.0, 158.0], [155.0, 159.0], [155.0, 160.0], [155.0, 161.0], [155.0, 162.0], [155.0, 163.0], [154.0, 168.0], [154.0, 169.0], [154.0, 170.0], [154.0, 171.0], [154.0, 172.0], [154.0, 173.0], [154.0, 174.0], [154.0, 175.0], [154.0, 176.0], [154.0, 177.0], [154.0, 178.0], [154.0, 179.0], [154.0, 180.0], [154.0, 181.0], [154.0, 182.0], [154.0, 183.0], [154.0, 195.0], [154.0, 196.0], [154.0, 197.0], [154.0, 198.0], [154.0, 199.0], [154.0, 200.0], [154.0, 201.0], [154.0, 202.0], [154.0, 203.0], [154.0, 204.0], [154.0, 205.0], [154.0, 206.0], [154.0, 207.0], [154.0, 208.0], [154.0, 209.0], [154.0, 210.0], [154.0, 211.0], [154.0, 212.0], [154.0, 213.0], [154.0, 214.0], [154.0, 215.0], [154.0, 216.0], [154.0, 217.0], [154.0, 218.0], [154.0, 219.0], [154.0, 220.0], [154.0, 221.0], [154.0, 222.0], [153.0, 234.0], [153.0, 235.0], [153.0, 236.0]]`

Arc1

`[[46.0, 128.0], [47.0, 128.0], [64.0, 129.0], [65.0, 129.0], [66.0, 129.0], [67.0, 129.0], [68.0, 129.0], [76.0, 130.0], [77.0, 130.0], [78.0, 130.0], [79.0, 130.0], [80.0, 130.0], [81.0, 130.0], [82.0, 130.0], [90.0, 131.0], [102.0, 132.0], [103.0, 132.0], [104.0, 132.0], [105.0, 132.0], [106.0, 132.0], [107.0, 132.0], [108.0, 132.0], [109.0, 132.0], [117.0, 133.0], [118.0, 133.0], [119.0, 133.0], [120.0, 133.0], [121.0, 133.0], [122.0, 133.0], [123.0, 133.0], [124.0, 133.0], [125.0, 133.0], [126.0, 133.0], [127.0, 133.0], [128.0, 133.0], [129.0, 133.0], [137.0, 134.0], [138.0, 134.0], [139.0, 134.0], [140.0, 134.0], [141.0, 134.0], [142.0, 134.0], [143.0, 134.0], [144.0, 134.0], [145.0, 134.0], [146.0, 134.0], [147.0, 134.0], [148.0, 134.0], [149.0, 134.0], [160.0, 134.0], [161.0, 134.0], [162.0, 134.0], [163.0, 134.0], [164.0, 134.0], [165.0, 134.0], [166.0, 134.0], [167.0, 134.0], [168.0, 134.0], [169.0, 134.0], [305.0, 134.0], [306.0, 134.0], [307.0, 134.0], [308.0, 134.0], [309.0, 134.0], [310.0, 134.0], [311.0, 134.0], [312.0, 134.0], [177.0, 135.0], [178.0, 135.0], [179.0, 135.0], [180.0, 135.0], [181.0, 135.0], [182.0, 135.0], [183.0, 135.0], [184.0, 135.0], [185.0, 135.0], [186.0, 135.0], [187.0, 135.0], [188.0, 135.0], [189.0, 135.0], [190.0, 135.0], [191.0, 135.0], [192.0, 135.0], [193.0, 135.0], [194.0, 135.0], [195.0, 135.0], [196.0, 135.0], [197.0, 135.0], [198.0, 135.0], [199.0, 135.0], [200.0, 135.0], [201.0, 135.0], [202.0, 135.0], [203.0, 135.0], [204.0, 135.0], [205.0, 135.0], [206.0, 135.0], [207.0, 135.0], [208.0, 135.0], [209.0, 135.0], [267.0, 135.0], [268.0, 135.0], [269.0, 135.0], [270.0, 135.0], [271.0, 135.0], [272.0, 135.0], [273.0, 135.0], [274.0, 135.0], [275.0, 135.0], [276.0, 135.0], [277.0, 135.0], [278.0, 135.0], [279.0, 135.0], [280.0, 135.0], [281.0, 135.0], [282.0, 135.0], [283.0, 135.0], [284.0, 135.0], [285.0, 135.0], [286.0, 135.0], [287.0, 135.0], [288.0, 135.0], [289.0, 135.0], [219.0, 136.0], [220.0, 136.0], [221.0, 136.0], [222.0, 136.0], [223.0, 136.0], [224.0, 136.0], [225.0, 136.0], [226.0, 136.0], [227.0, 136.0], [228.0, 136.0], [229.0, 136.0], [230.0, 136.0], [231.0, 136.0], [232.0, 136.0], [233.0, 136.0], [234.0, 136.0], [235.0, 136.0], [236.0, 136.0], [237.0, 136.0], [238.0, 136.0], [239.0, 136.0], [240.0, 136.0], [241.0, 136.0], [242.0, 136.0], [243.0, 136.0], [244.0, 136.0], [245.0, 136.0], [246.0, 136.0], [247.0, 136.0], [248.0, 136.0], [249.0, 136.0], [250.0, 136.0], [251.0, 136.0], [252.0, 136.0], [253.0, 136.0]]`

Arc2:

`[[212.0, 2.0], [212.0, 3.0], [212.0, 4.0], [212.0, 5.0], [213.0, 10.0], [213.0, 11.0], [213.0, 12.0], [213.0, 13.0], [213.0, 14.0], [214.0, 19.0], [215.0, 31.0], [215.0, 32.0], [215.0, 33.0], [215.0, 34.0], [216.0, 39.0], [216.0, 40.0], [216.0, 41.0], [216.0, 42.0], [216.0, 43.0], [216.0, 44.0], [216.0, 45.0], [216.0, 46.0], [216.0, 47.0], [216.0, 48.0], [216.0, 49.0], [216.0, 50.0], [217.0, 55.0], [217.0, 56.0], [217.0, 57.0], [217.0, 58.0], [217.0, 59.0], [217.0, 60.0], [217.0, 61.0], [217.0, 62.0], [217.0, 63.0], [217.0, 64.0], [217.0, 65.0], [217.0, 66.0], [217.0, 67.0], [217.0, 68.0], [217.0, 69.0], [217.0, 70.0], [217.0, 71.0], [217.0, 81.0], [217.0, 82.0], [217.0, 83.0], [217.0, 84.0], [217.0, 85.0], [217.0, 86.0], [217.0, 87.0], [217.0, 88.0], [217.0, 89.0], [217.0, 90.0], [217.0, 91.0], [217.0, 92.0], [217.0, 93.0], [217.0, 94.0], [217.0, 95.0], [217.0, 96.0], [217.0, 97.0], [217.0, 98.0], [217.0, 99.0], [217.0, 100.0], [217.0, 101.0], [217.0, 102.0], [217.0, 103.0], [216.0, 108.0], [216.0, 109.0], [216.0, 110.0], [216.0, 111.0], [216.0, 112.0], [216.0, 113.0], [216.0, 114.0], [216.0, 115.0], [216.0, 116.0], [216.0, 117.0], [216.0, 118.0], [216.0, 119.0], [216.0, 120.0], [216.0, 121.0], [216.0, 122.0], [216.0, 123.0], [215.0, 128.0], [215.0, 129.0], [215.0, 130.0], [215.0, 140.0], [215.0, 141.0], [215.0, 142.0], [214.0, 147.0], [214.0, 148.0], [214.0, 149.0], [214.0, 150.0], [214.0, 151.0], [214.0, 152.0], [213.0, 157.0], [213.0, 158.0], [213.0, 159.0], [213.0, 160.0], [213.0, 161.0], [212.0, 166.0], [212.0, 167.0], [212.0, 168.0], [212.0, 169.0]]`

Arc3:

`[[108.0, 72.0], [109.0, 72.0], [110.0, 72.0], [111.0, 72.0], [112.0, 72.0], [113.0, 72.0], [114.0, 72.0], [115.0, 72.0], [116.0, 72.0], [117.0, 72.0], [118.0, 72.0], [119.0, 72.0], [120.0, 72.0], [121.0, 72.0], [122.0, 72.0], [123.0, 72.0], [124.0, 72.0], [125.0, 72.0], [126.0, 72.0], [127.0, 72.0], [128.0, 72.0], [129.0, 72.0], [130.0, 72.0], [131.0, 72.0], [132.0, 72.0], [133.0, 72.0], [134.0, 72.0], [135.0, 72.0], [136.0, 72.0], [137.0, 72.0], [138.0, 72.0], [139.0, 72.0], [140.0, 72.0], [141.0, 72.0], [142.0, 72.0], [143.0, 72.0], [144.0, 72.0], [145.0, 72.0], [146.0, 72.0], [147.0, 72.0], [148.0, 72.0], [149.0, 72.0], [150.0, 72.0], [162.0, 73.0], [163.0, 73.0], [164.0, 73.0], [165.0, 73.0], [166.0, 73.0], [167.0, 73.0], [168.0, 73.0], [169.0, 73.0], [170.0, 73.0], [171.0, 73.0], [172.0, 73.0], [173.0, 73.0], [174.0, 73.0], [175.0, 73.0], [176.0, 73.0], [177.0, 73.0], [178.0, 73.0], [80.0, 74.0], [81.0, 74.0], [82.0, 74.0], [83.0, 74.0], [84.0, 74.0], [85.0, 74.0], [86.0, 74.0], [87.0, 74.0], [186.0, 74.0], [187.0, 74.0], [188.0, 74.0], [189.0, 74.0], [190.0, 74.0], [191.0, 74.0], [192.0, 74.0], [193.0, 74.0], [71.0, 75.0], [72.0, 75.0], [201.0, 75.0], [202.0, 75.0], [203.0, 75.0], [204.0, 75.0], [205.0, 75.0], [61.0, 76.0], [62.0, 76.0], [63.0, 76.0]]`

Arc4:

`[[98.0, 83.0], [98.0, 84.0], [98.0, 85.0], [98.0, 86.0], [98.0, 87.0], [98.0, 88.0], [98.0, 89.0], [98.0, 90.0], [98.0, 91.0], [98.0, 92.0], [98.0, 93.0], [98.0, 94.0], [98.0, 95.0], [98.0, 96.0], [97.0, 101.0], [97.0, 102.0], [97.0, 103.0], [97.0, 104.0], [97.0, 105.0], [97.0, 106.0], [97.0, 107.0], [97.0, 108.0], [97.0, 109.0], [97.0, 110.0], [97.0, 111.0], [97.0, 112.0], [97.0, 113.0], [97.0, 114.0], [97.0, 115.0], [97.0, 116.0], [97.0, 117.0], [97.0, 118.0], [97.0, 119.0], [97.0, 120.0], [97.0, 121.0], [97.0, 122.0], [97.0, 123.0], [97.0, 124.0], [97.0, 125.0], [97.0, 126.0], [98.0, 138.0], [98.0, 139.0], [98.0, 140.0], [98.0, 141.0], [98.0, 142.0], [98.0, 143.0], [98.0, 144.0], [98.0, 145.0], [98.0, 146.0], [98.0, 147.0], [98.0, 148.0], [98.0, 149.0], [98.0, 150.0], [98.0, 151.0], [98.0, 152.0], [99.0, 157.0], [99.0, 158.0], [99.0, 159.0], [99.0, 160.0], [99.0, 161.0], [99.0, 162.0], [99.0, 163.0], [99.0, 164.0], [99.0, 165.0], [99.0, 166.0], [100.0, 171.0], [100.0, 172.0], [100.0, 173.0], [100.0, 174.0], [100.0, 175.0], [100.0, 176.0], [100.0, 177.0], [102.0, 194.0], [102.0, 195.0], [102.0, 196.0], [102.0, 197.0], [103.0, 202.0], [103.0, 203.0], [103.0, 204.0], [104.0, 208.0], [104.0, 209.0], [104.0, 210.0], [105.0, 214.0], [105.0, 215.0], [105.0, 216.0]]`

Comment: Thanks for asking a follow-up question from this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77834588/optimization-with-a-nested-set-of-constraints I'm including the link for those who would like to see the prior discussion.

Comment: @JohnHedengren do you think it is best to try to formulate the objective function in a different manner, or is it possible to implement something like this with Gekko?

Comment: The procedure of guessing optimal values, calculating Horner polynomials, calculating difference to a linear regression, and then guessing optimal values again wouldn't fit into the framework of Gekko. In Gekko, the model variables and equations are all compiled and solved simultaneously with no call-backs to the python script. The functions are called only when the model is defined. When the solver takes over, the model and data are compiled to byte code for efficient solution.

Comment: If it is only two variables, then it is possible to evaluate the objective at combinations of `K1` and `K2` and then optimize the b-spline approximation of the objective function such as shown with this example: https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ObjectBspline My guess is that the procedural nature of this optimization problem would lend itself better to a gradient-free method. Gradient-free methods are typically much slower, but do better if the objective function is non-convex and it needs to find the globally optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHedengren, I will have a look at implementing this approach