# pulp: Schedule equipment replacement, maximizing Total Cost (considering devaluation)

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

Given `init_age=3` years, `init_cost=4` of equipment, and `new_eq_cost=18`, schedule replacement time, given data for
`cost= np.array([31, 30, 28, 28, 27, 26, 26, 25, 24, 24, 23 ])` & `depreciation= np.array([ 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18])` yearly.

I tried to use [PuLP](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/), but it seems that either my objective or my constraints or both are not correct; and besides I cannot output [binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134522/converting-conditional-constraints-to-linear-constraints-in-linear-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1) desicion `y_variable` (`true` if replacement is needed):

```
import numpy as np
from pulp import *

##M=100000
time_count= 12
tm= np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
cost_count= 12
cost= np.array([4,31, 30, 28, 28, 27, 26, 26, 25, 24, 24, 23 ])
depreciation= np.array([0, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18])
#depreciated_cost= np.array([cost[i]-depreciation[i] for i in range(time_count)])
##print("depreciated_cost:", depreciated_cost)

# subject to constraints
init_age=3      # 3 yr
init_cost= 4
new_cost= 18    # <<<<<<<<<<<<

# ... FROM 1st case
##replace_cost= init_cost - new_cost + cost[0] - depreciation[0]      # if is negative - then should be replaced
##print(replace_cost)

    # Create the model
model = LpProblem(name="equipment replacement shedule", sense=LpMinimize)   # TODO: Maximize Cost

    # Initialize the DECISION VARIABLES
x_variables = LpVariable.dicts("x_time_cost", [(t,j) for t in tm for j in range(cost_count)],lowBound=0, upBound=None, cat='Integer')
y_variables = LpVariable.dicts("indicator_cons", [(j) for j in tm ], cat='Binary')       # true - if replace needed  

    # Add the CONSTRAINTS to the model ???
for t in tm:    # IF SUM OK ?
        model += (lpSum([x_variables[(t, j)] - depreciation[j] for j in range(cost_count)]) <= new_cost, "Constraint on Cost{} for replacement".format(t))

for j in range(cost_count):
        model += (
            lpSum([x_variables[(t, j)] - depreciation[j]  for t in tm]) >= 1 * y_variables[j], "One_assignment_constraint{}".format(j))

    # Add the OBJECTIVE function to the model ???
model += lpSum(x_variables)

    # The problem data is written to an .lp file
model.writeLP("Equipment_Replacement.lp")

    # Solve the problem
status = None
time_limit = 900
status = model.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=0, timeLimit=time_limit, threads=1))

print("-------------------------------------------------------")
print(f"status: {model.status}, {LpStatus[model.status]}")
print(f"objective: {model.objective.value()}")

for var in model.variables():
    if var.value()==9.0:
       print(f"{var.name}: {var.value()}")

for name, constraint in model.constraints.items():
       print(f"{name}: {constraint.value()}")
```

I included `init_cost` of equipment as the first element to the array `cost` - was I right? And how to output binary conditional variables pointing to the year for replacement? Output of total cost maximized is also needed.

Solution should show:

1. use equipment with `init_age` 3 years for 2 years, then replace it with new & use it for 3th, 4th, 5th, 6th year, again replace with new & use it for 7th, 8th, 9th, 10th year
2. maximized total cost should be 169 (in correct answer) - but I cannot achieve it.

I am trying to solve this scheduling problem for the first time & cannot understand it yet, even how to correctly write a mathematical model. Though debugging `Constraint_on_Cost_for_replacement` seems to show time-points for replacement (when accounting becomes negative) -- I still cannot show it with binary `y_variable` (if it is needed here ?) and I still doubt that using `LpMinimize` is adequate here if task is to formulate the problem of cost maximization. How can I correct my model to reach the correct answer given?

P.S. or could [GEKKO Logical Functions](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html#logical-functions) be easier to use for such a task like mine?

Comment: p.s. [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/102096/how-to-visualize-optimization-problems-feasible-region?rq=1) is interesting/useful topic *How to visualize optimization problems' feasible region*

Comment: well, I see now the number from my exercise: `depreciated_cost= np.array([cost[i]-depreciation[i] for i in range(time_count)]).sum()`=169 given, but need just to maximize NOT `x_variables`, but `y_variables` as a result of `cost-depreciation` subtraction SIGN... perhaps, exercise's answer (was given according Bellman equation in book) logics is different while solving in PuLP & in PuLP does not refer to the Bellman's solution ?

Comment: as so as Task seems to be fully Linear, big-M seems to be unneeded here as constraint. If I am right in such a statement ?

Comment: @comment#2 not maximize, but just mark the year_

Comment: [penalty for non-integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110848/how-to-optimize-for-integer-parameters-and-other-discontinuous-parameter-space) or [here](https://optimization-online.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/2441.pdf) or [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/15-084j-nonlinear-programming-spring-2004/13b4c46d590cf3df94475e0ae1a815c3_lec10_penalty_mt.pdf) - if in *Scipy* without milp (that appears in v.1.9 only)

Comment: p.s. [mip pckg](https://python-mip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) also works

Comment: This question is a mess.  It isn't clear why you are making so many comments....  Just ask a clear question.  The basic construct of your question isn't clear.  What is `init_cost`?  What does the cost vector mean?  Why would I replace anything at all?  the math isn't clear (forget about the LP until it is).  I suggest you (a) remove the non-answer below, (b) edit your original question to show a **simple example** of how the pieces fit together to make a minimum cost model from some basic data.

Answer (score 0):

I will simplify the initial code to  make it  easier to read & remove combinatons (according to comment), but still cannot cope with `objective` & `constraints` to assign `binary` replacement moment(s) to `maximize` total_Cost_for_the_whole_period.

```
from pulp import *
import numpy as np

time_count=11
tm= np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
cost= np.array([ 31, 30, 28, 28, 27, 26, 26, 25, 24, 24, 23 ])
depreciation= np.array([ 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18])
d= np.array([cost[i]-depreciation[i] for i in range(time_count)])   # depreciated_Cost
new_cost=18
init_cost=4  # 3 year-old current available equipment

# create model
model = LpProblem("Example 2", LpMaximize)

# create variable dict
y = LpVariable.dict('x',  cat='Binary', indices=tm )

# set OBJ function => (binary_mark + cost )
model += lpSum(y[(i)] for i in tm) + lpSum(y[(i)]* (d[i] + init_cost - new_cost) for i in tm)

# add CONS
for i in tm:
    model += lpSum([ y[(i)] * d[i] ]) <= new_cost * y[(i)]     # ??

# solve model
model.solve()

# print solution
for i in tm:
        print(f"{y[(i)].name}: {y[(i)].value()}")

#######################

x_soln = np.array([y[i].varValue for i in range(time_count)])
print(x_soln)
print("\n\ntime: ", tm)
##print("depreciated_Cost: ", d)
print("x_soln: ", x_soln)
```

p.s.
this code is given according to the comment above without combinatons, but only with `(j)` - perhaps, there's really nothing to optimize at all, because `depreciated_cost= np.array([cost[i]-depreciation[i] +  (0 if (cost[i]- d[i])>0 else 1)*new_cost for i in range(time_count)]).sum()` gives exactly `169` , as in the dynamic programming solution, that was given with Bellman equation, where the task is given from

p.p.s. I didn't change the OP (with `(t,j)` combinations), because in that code there were seen, at least, moments of cost becoming negative, where assignments for replacement could be --  it seems that `(t,j)` gives an opportunity to recognize time-points for replacements (t acting as **sensor**, j acting as **counter** of sequence)

OR it would be better to *reformulate* the task (?) - to get the possibility to point to time periods where replacements are needed - if it's right?

```
Maximize sum(zi) 
Subject to
  zi <= x + y                            
  xi <= 18                                              
  x are real 
  y are binary
```

Comment: ? perhaps, [such](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6187/how-can-i-strengthen-a-family-of-constraints-in-the-presence-of-a-clique-constra) a formulation is more correct